# Can't set the first ListView item with custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I use a custom adapter, a Message class etc... I can't update the very first one ListItem, the second and the others are correctly added in my Listview. By updating I mean I have the name of the textView's text  by default and not the message!

Could you help me to understand why ? Thank you!
Here's a part of the code :
(The listView is in a dialog window)

```
 // (variables put in public static)
 chat_dialogue = new Dialog(context, R.style.hidetitle);                    
 chat_dialogue.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
 chat_dialogue.setContentView(R.layout.wakeupcalls); // show the dialogue                   
 edit_Text_Chat = (EditText) chat_dialogue.findViewById(R.id.editText_chat);                
 chat_listView = (ListView)chat_dialogue.findViewById(R.id.ListViewChat);

 Fsa.messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

 Fsa.messages.add(new Message(the_sender,the_message,"(" + Fsa.date + Fsa.pre_mess2 + Fsa.heure + ")",true));

 adapter = new bubbleadapter(context,messages);

 chat_listView.setAdapter(adapter);                 
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
 chat_listView.setSelection(messages.size()-1);
```

Then I add some new Messages from others methods they display perfectly but not this one above! (as I said it's just the first one!)

Now the custom adapter :

```
public class bubbleadapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Message> mMessages;


public bubbleadapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages){
    super();        
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mMessages = messages;

}
@Override
public int getCount(){      
    return mMessages.size();

}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return mMessages.get(position);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     Message message = (Message) this.getItem(position);


    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView ==null) {           
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_row, parent,false);
        holder.sender = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVSender);
        holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text1);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVDate);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {


        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.sender.setText(message.getSender());
        holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
        holder.date.setText(message.getDate());

        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();

        if (message.isStatusMessage()) {

            holder.message.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            holder.sender.setText(message.getSender());         
                holder.sender.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#405478"));

        } else {

            if (message.isMine()) {                 
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);                   
                lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            } else {                    
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            }
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);             
        }           
    }

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
     TextView sender;
     TextView message;
     TextView date;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {       
    return position;
}

 }
```

Comment: could you add your Custom Adapter getView() function code,it would be useful to solve your case. why do you use chat_listView.setSelection(messages.size()-1);?

Comment: Ok. I pasted it ! I use the setSelection for controlling my listView if I want to update one item without adding a new message...

Comment: please add the code that you used to add the other messages. I think that the problem is there.

Comment: looks like you are resetting the messages.

Comment: can you up vote the answer please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the else statement as follow:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     Message message = (Message) this.getItem(position);


ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView ==null) {           
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_row, parent,false);
    holder.sender = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVSender);
    holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text1);
    holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVDate);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} 


    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.sender.setText(message.getSender());
    holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
    holder.date.setText(message.getDate());

    LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();

    if (message.isStatusMessage()) {

        holder.message.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        holder.sender.setText(message.getSender());         
            holder.sender.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#405478"));

    } else {

        if (message.isMine()) {                 
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);                   
            lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        } else {                    
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        }
        holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);             
    }           


return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Good try but it doesn't change nothing ! Still the same problem, I really don't know why only the first message...It doesn't make sense or a problem with the `chat_listView.setAdapter(adapter)` ?

Comment: maybe this is not your only problem. but, for sure that's one of them you had an uncorrect logic for this method. I will investigate more in your code to find other problems and I will edit my answer.

Comment: I made a workaround because I don't have the choice (I don't get it!). So I added directly after the set tag the getTag til the end of the last else. It works this way.